# How to divide total price into sum of multiple of numbers

Tags: divisor-sum

How to divide total price into sum of multiple of numbers so that the sum is close to price as much as possible.
Is there any formula?

Example:
Price: 1256.7

Numbers: 5.7, 3.6, 4.9, 10.1, 12.3, 6.8

Sulution should look like:  1256.7 = 5x5.7 + 30x3.6 + 0x4.9 ....

I search for a formula to find how to get close to price using sum of multiple Numbers

Comment: Assuming the numbers must be rational, WLOG we can suppose they are integers, in which case this generalizes the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is known to be [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete).